# How to intergrate lex with lambda in amazon aws?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have a simple bot with the following logic.

Bot: select one of the following item your interested

```
 (response card)
 -ecommerce
 -travel etc
```

Human : clicks eg travel

Bot: response card

```
 -marketing 

 -digital
```

Here is what I have in my lambda function

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const sessionAttributes = event.sessionAttributes;
    const slots = event.currentIntent.slots;
    const videommerceType = slots.videommerceType;


    // predefined list of available pizza
    const validData = ['ecommerce', 'startup', 'lead generation', 'crm', 'travel'];


    // negative check: if valid slot value is not obtained, inform lex that user is expected 
    // respond with a slot value 
    if (videommerceType && !(videommerceType === "") && validData.indexOf(videommerceType.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
        let response = {
            sessionAttributes: event.sessionAttributes,
            dialogAction: {
                type : "'ElicitSlot",
                message: {
                    contentType: "PlainText or SSML",
                    content: "Message to convey to the user. For example, Thanks, your pizza has been ordered."
                },
                responseCard: {
                    version: "1",
                    contentType: "application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic",
                    genericAttachments: [{
                        title: "card-title",
                        subTitle: "card-sub-title",
                        imageUrl: "URL of the image to be shown",
                        attachmentLinkUrl: "URL of the attachment to be associated with the card",
                        buttons: [{
                            text: "button-text",
                            value: "Value sent to server on button click"
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
        callback(null, response);
    }


    let response = {
        sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: "Delegate",
            slots: event.currentIntent.slots
        }
    }
    callback(null, response);
};
```

Unfortunately this not working, on lex bot I get the following error

```
Intent videommerceIntent is ReadyForFulfillment: name:jim videommerceType:ecommerce
```

What is wrong with my code? any help or similar working demo would be appreciated , thanks

Comment: follow this guide : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs2-prepare.html and you will understand all the steps

Comment: You may have the "Lambda Initialization and Validation" section pointing to your Lambda Function, but not have it configured for the "Fulfillment" section. So double check that.